# Why does the funnel on my boiler clog and leak?

Tags: plumbing, leak

I apologize if I don't use the right terminology, please correct me.

I have this boiler system called Grohe Red. Here is [the manual](https://www.manua.ls/grohe/red-duo/manual?p=8).

The problem I have is that every now and then the "funnel" (that's how the manual calls that black thing) gets clogged with junk from the sink. The boiler system releases some water droplets at each use and they overflow from the funnel when it's clogged, resulting in water on the floor of the kitchen.

As a temporary solution I just clean the s**t out of the funnel every time it's clogged.
I believe this is not the correct way of installing such a system, as junk from the sink can easily get into the funnel and clog it.

Can somebody advise me on how to fix this?

Also, is it a problem that the brass junction is corroded, or is it fine?

[image: Overall installation]

[image: Close up of the mounting 1]

[image: Close up of the mounting 2]

Comment: Figure 3 shows 'the funnel' *"min 50(mm?)"* below the other thing. [This manual here is a thread instead of pages](https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91vPXJkA3UL.pdf), PDF. "Mount safety relief valve kit to the waste pipe, see Figs. [3] to [6]."

Answer (score 1):

1. Disconnect the funnel from the 90 degree fitting (red X) and connect it instead to the Y fitting just above.  *Connect it with a plastic tube, not directly*. ....
2. Then the whole assembly in the yellow circle will be free-floating.  Raise it up as high as possible, up between the sink and wall.
3. Clamp it to the wall so it doesn't bang around.

This will collect much less sink debris, perhaps none.
[image]